# Add a Custom Back Button to a Custom Navigation Bar

Tags: swift

I have been trying to add a custom back button to a Nav Bar that is being created on Load as I am using a Multi-Storyboard set-up, so the back button will not appear automatically, plus I am trying to use a custom image for it.

This is what I have so far:

```
class AddFundsMethodTable : UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.styleNavBar()
}

func styleNavBar() {
    var newNavBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 100.0))
    newNavBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Choose a Method")
    var backImage = UIImage(named: "backBtn")
    var backItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backButton:")
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
    newNavBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

    self.view.addSubview(newNavBar)
}

func backButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

}

Comment: Which problem will occur?????

Comment: Oh right, the Button doesn't show up.

Comment: when button doesn't show up????

Comment: When the view load, all I can see is the Nav Bar title, no Button Bar items...

Comment: In ViewDidload call function

Comment: you have image for back button ? any spelling mistake in image name or something, so its not able to set image for button.

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewDidLoad` write this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.styleNavBar()
}
```

Comment: This does not make a difference, the function is being called where it was before as I can see the top nav bar with the title, the issue is the button bar item does not show up